# How to add a toolbar to a UIPickerView subclass?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview, subclass

I've created a UIPickerView subclass, I've completed the implementation of the picker view itself.

What I would like to do however is to add a toolbar above the picker view as part of the new class. How and where should I do this in the subclass implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add both the picker and the toolbar to another view and use that as your "control"

Comment: I ended up creating a UIView subclass that contained the picker and the toolbar...thanks